# How to extract strings from nested symbols?

Tags: python, regex, string

Sorry, I don't know how to name this thread.

I need to extract the first layer of `()` with `""` from `string` but when I try to use `re` it only returns everything in between first and second `()`.

```
import re

string = 'this is a test ("string with (some) paranthesis") how great'
extract = re.findall('\((.*?)\)', string)

print(extract)
```

Output:

```
['"string with (some']
```

But I need:

```
['"string with (some) paranthesis"']
```

or without the `""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a greedy quantifier instead of a lazy one:

```
extract = re.findall('\((.*)\)', string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `?`:

```
import re

string = 'this is a test ("string with (some) paranthesis") how great'
extract = re.findall(r'\((.*)\)', string)

print(extract)
```

The `?` was not redundant because you already have `.*` to match everything between parentheses; it makes the match non-greedy, meaning that `.*` will match the shortest sequence of characters ending with parentheses, which is `("string with (some)`.

Comment: Well that was easy. Thanks. Will award in few minutes.

Comment: `?` isn't redundant here, it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Depending how specific you need to be, you can try the following:

```
import re

string = 'this is a test ("string with (some) paranthesis") how great'
extract = re.findall(r'\((".*?")\)', string)
```

The pattern `'\((.*)\)'` will not work correctly if there are subsequent parentheses in the string e.g.

```
string = 'this is a test ("string with (some) paranthesis") how (really) great'
```

Then, depending on your strings `r'\((".*?")\)'` may be not appropriate too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple split would be sufficient for your needs:

```
string  = 'this is a test ("string with (some) paranthesis") how great'

extract = string.split("(",1)[-1].rsplit(")",1)[0]

print(extract)
# "string with (some) paranthesis"
```